# How to copy to specific path over ssh to a Windows server with Fabric?

Tags: python, ssh, fabric, paramiko

How can you copy a file or folder over SSH to a specific folder (absolute path) in a remote Windows server ? Is it possible to use the remote server's environment variables to specify that path?

If I use fabric's put operation:

```
put('somedir')
```

or

```
put('somedir', '.')
```

Without a destination, it will create the folder in the user's Desktop folder in the destination and copy its contents (I have no idea why that is the default folder, and I couldn't change it through the freesshd daemon used on the windows server)

If I try using:

```
put('somedir', '/Users/me')

put('somedir', 'c:/Users/me')

put('somedir', './testdir')
```

Or:

```
put('somedir', 'c:\\Users\\me')
```

It will fail with permission denied (an error in paramiko's sftp_client.mkdir).

Comment: Its likely that its trying to rewrite the me dir with all the contents of somedir. Did you try `/Users/me/` ?